# Import recipe into Google Cloud Data Fusion pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Is it possible to import a recipe exported from dataprep into a pipeline in Data Fusion?

Answer (score 5):

No unfortunately they are currently not compatible and you cannot export a recipe from Cloud Dataprep (Wrangler) and import to Cloud Data Fusion (Wrangler). Two distinct engines/services, Cloud Dataprep based on [Trifacta](https://www.trifacta.com/) and Cloud Data Fusion from OSS [CDAP](https://cdap.io/)